# get commits since a particular date in git based on commit date

Tags: git, git-commit

To get commits after a particular date. I can do this:

```
git log <ref> --since=<date> --pretty=format:%ci
```

This seems to list commits based on author date. How do I get commits after a particular date *based on commit time* ? I can parse the output of above cmd to get what I desire, however I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure 'git log' to show 'commit date'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243380/how-to-configure-git-log-to-show-commit-date)

Comment: Yes, i can parse the output of the cmd in the question and filter commits based on the commit date. Is there a better way to do it though ?

Comment: Looking through the code my initial take is "you can't", but it looks like a great opportunity to submit a patch to git :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with git 1.9.1. `--since`/`--until` use the commit timestamp here: http://pastebin.com/yYDVyqxc

Comment: I dont think you can do what you ask for - since git is a DVCS. Each commit is into the "master" copy of a repository ie each repo is a clone. Thus, the commit is in the same universal (ie relatively local) time ie local to that machine. Not sure if that confuses you even more.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your query is not that clear to me but I would like to answer with best of my understanding:
as we know, with ref: http://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

```
%ai: author date, ISO 8601-like format
%ci: committer date, ISO 8601-like format
```

Is this of any help? Using **--after** and **--before** to get results in between. Like below uses same date with results between time (*10:36AM to 04:50PM of June 22, 2015*) with **%ci** for committer date

```
git log --after="2015-06-22T10:36:00-07:00" --before="2015-06-22T16:50:00-07:00" --pretty=format:%ci
```

Comment: Just a note, the date string is pretty flexible. For example, `--after="2020-08-28"` also works.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is no way here to tweak `git log` here since it is internally implemented to use *commit date* for `before`, `after`, `since`, `until` parameters. In general, the default Git's strategy for comparing dates is by *commit date*.

Answer (score 0):

If you use %cr instead of %ci, at least you only have time references. But they are relative, like '2 hours ago'.