# Git select ansestor based on commit date

Tags: git, command-line, revision

I can do `HEAD@{30d}` to get where my `HEAD` was 30d ago. But this is based on the local reflog. It won't contain commits that I never checked out and may contain other branches that I switched to even if they were never merged into current `HEAD`.

Is there a way to do something similar but following the commit ancestry instead? I'm thinking something like `HEAD~{30d}` which would be interpreted as "walk the first parents of `HEAD` and return the first commit with a committed date older than 30 days old.

I want this because I frequently use `git bisect` to track down a problem, and often I don't know exactly when it started. So I want do something like `git bisect HEAD HEAD~{30d}` to look for a change in the last 30 days. Right now I am working around this by using `git log` to select the commit.

```bash
git bisect start HEAD $(git log -n1 --pretty=format:%H --before '30 days ago')
```

This works but is much less convenient. It seems surprising that there isn't a syntax for what seems like a common query.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704128/get-commits-since-a-particular-date-in-git-based-on-commit-date

Comment: Seems like you want `main@...` or `<branchname>@...` instead of `HEAD`? This rev. syntax will “walk” according to the ref that you give.

Comment: `main@...` This doesn't seem to walk the rev. "warning: log for 'main' only goes back to Mon, 22 Jan 2024". [gitrevisions docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) also disagree with you. They say that `@` always uses the reflog no matter what is in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

> `git log -n1 --pretty=format:%H --before '30 days ago` — works but is much less convenient.

You can do much better.

```
git rev-list -1 --before=30days @
```

and if you're doing it a lot you can make an alias, with some use of the option syntax flexibility,

```
git config --global alias.bef 'git rev-list -1 @ --before'
```

then `git bef 30days` prints it.

You might want to add `--first-parent` to avoid getting disoriented in thickly-branched ancestry.