# How to make `git log` show only the commit date, nothing else

Tags: git, date, git-log

I just want to get a quick glance at the history of a project by having `git log` show *only* the commit date, nothing else. How can we best do that?

---

#### Update:

It turns out I was actually asking for the **author** date, which is what is shown by `git log`. To see the **committer** date too, which can be different, run `git log --pretty=fuller`.

See also here: [Why is git AuthorDate different from CommitDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11857467/4561887)

To help make this point that there are different dates: to set an **author** date when running `git commit`, use:

```sh
git commit ---date "<date>"
```

To set also the **committer** date, you'd have to do:

```sh
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="<date>" git commit --date "<date>"
```

See here: [How can one change the timestamp of an old commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9701130/4561887)

Comment: Kind of related: [How to configure 'git log' to show 'commit date'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14243380/4561887)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see only the **committer** date (the date the commit was written with it's current ID):

```
git log --format=%cd
```

If you want to see only the **author** date (the date the commit was originally written, but may differ from the committer date if the commit was amended, rebased, cherry-picked, etc, which caused it to get a new commit ID):

```
git log --format=%ad
```

More info on the difference between committer and author dates: [Why git AuthorDate is different from CommitDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11857467/184546).

Dates can be displayed in different ways. [Here's a list of built-in options.](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats#Documentation/pretty-formats.txt-emHem)

Also, if you don't want to use a pager, just add `--no-pager` after the `git` command, like this:

```
git --no-pager log --format=%ad
```

Comment: So when someone first types in `git commit` for a brand-new set of changes, and a timestamp is added to the commit message, is that considered the "commiter" date or the "author" date, or both?

Comment: @GabrielStaples in that case, both dates would be the same. You can view the current log to see them both and get an idea of when they differ, using: `git log --pretty=fuller`. Equally importantly as those dates differing, is that the people doing them can differ too!

Comment: Docs for different formatting can be found here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emHem

Comment: @Fusion that link looks a lot like the one in the answer, despite being a different url. ;)

Answer (score 1):

### 1. The easy way:

(This answer was the first answer; this part was added after @TTT wrote [the comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71384830/how-to-make-git-log-show-only-the-commit-date-nothing-else/71384831#comment126177882_71384831%20%20%20%5B2%5D:%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/71385517/4561887) which taught me this easier way).

```
# ad = author date
git log --format=%ad

# cd = committer date
git log --format=%cd
```

`%cd` stands for "Committer Date", apparently. Contrast that with `%ad`, which stands for "Author Date". (I'm not sure what the differences are nor how or why these dates would differ).

Thank you, [@TTT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71384830/how-to-make-git-log-show-only-the-commit-date-nothing-else/71384831?noredirect=1#comment126177882_71384831). Now that I see how that works, I found the appropriate format string sections in the documentation:

Do `man git log`, then search for the regular expression `format:<format-string>` by pressing <kbd>/</kbd> and typing that in and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Searching for `%cd` also jumps down to that section.

### 2. The hard way (my initial attempt):

Tested on Linux Ubuntu:

One way to get the author date (`--format=%ad`, above, as I now know after-the-fact) is to filter the output of `git log` through `grep`. Here is the answer for `git log HEAD`. Replace `HEAD` with any branch name or commit hash you want.

**See just the dates for all commits:**

```sh
git log HEAD | grep 'Date:' | grep -o '   .*$' | grep -o '[^\r\n\t\f\v ].*$'
```

Sample output:

```
Sun Apr 26 19:17:49 2020 -0700
Sun Apr 26 16:51:21 2020 -0700
Sun Apr 26 15:35:16 2020 -0700
Sat Apr 25 23:21:37 2020 -0700
Sat Apr 25 23:12:07 2020 -0700
Sat Apr 25 23:06:44 2020 -0700
Tue Apr 14 23:02:34 2020 -0700
Sun Apr 5 23:26:20 2020 -0700
Sun Apr 5 23:20:34 2020 -0700
Sun Apr 5 18:08:44 2020 -0700
Sun Apr 5 17:56:08 2020 -0700
Sun Apr 5 10:06:04 2020 -0700
Sat Apr 4 20:58:33 2020 -0700
Sat Mar 21 14:38:53 2020 -0700
Thu Mar 19 20:37:27 2020 -0700
Thu Mar 19 18:16:55 2020 -0700
Thu Mar 19 18:01:53 2020 -0700
```

Or, to just see the **most-recent date only**, add `-1`:

```sh
git log -1 HEAD | grep 'Date:' | grep -o '   .*$' | grep -o '[^\r\n\t\f\v ].*$'
```

Output:

```
Sun Apr 26 19:17:49 2020 -0700
```

...or to see **just the *oldest* date**, use `$(git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD)` instead of `HEAD` (again, replace `HEAD` in that command with the appropriate branch or commit you'd like to view):

```sh
git log -1 $(git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD) | grep 'Date:' \
    | grep -o '   .*$' | grep -o '[^\r\n\t\f\v ].*$'
```

Output:

```
Thu Mar 19 18:01:53 2020 -0700
```

### Explanation

1. `$(git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD)` gets the commit hash of the first commit.

   1. See my answer here: [How to show first commit by 'git log'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68840032/4561887)
2. `grep 'Date:'` finds only lines with the text `Date:` in them.
3. `grep -o '   .*$'` strips off the `Date:` part by matching only the 3 spaces and the text following that.

   1. For the `-o` part, see: [Can grep show only words that match search pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546735/4561887)
4. `grep -o '[^\r\n\t\f\v ].*$'` strips off the preceding spaces by matching only non-whitespace chars.

   1. See my answer here: [Unix & Linux: Any non-whitespace regular expression](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/693317/114401)
5. `-1` in `git log` means: "just 1 commit"
6. `HEAD` is the currently-checked-out commit hash

Comment: I'm confused. Don't you just want `git log --format=%cd` ?

Comment: Also, your question says "commit" date which I assumed you meant "committer" date. Looks like this answer wanted "author" date.

Comment: @TTT, to your first question: yes, thank you. To your 2nd question: I don't understand the difference: what is the difference between committer date and author date? When might they differ? Why? Feel free to add that to your answer.

Comment: I updated my answer to explain the differences.